# How do I map CAPS LOCK to CTRL on OSX Emacs without doing it OS-wide

Tags: macos, emacs

I've been using Keyboard in System Preferences to map the CAPS LOCK key to CTRL.  However, it does this system-wide and I need it only for OSX emacs.  Now I'm using an application that requires a CAPS LOCK key.  Is there any way to map only for OSX Emacs?  Note, I'm not using Carbon emacs which I believe has explicit support for this.

The emacs wiki (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey#toc13) points to Keyboard in System Preferences and uControl, which is no longer maintained.  uControl points to fKeys (http://www.kodachi.com/software/fKeys/) which is reaching end of life.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just trade the Caps-Lock and CTRL keys?
Map the Caps-Lock to CTRL
Map the CTRL to Caps-Lock

You'll have the advantage of the better Control key, with the Caps-Lock available for the application that needs it.

- Chris

Comment: I've been using this technique since before MacOS X existed, and highly recommend it.  :)  (I also highly recommend use of the Dvorak keyboard layout, but that's another story, I suppose.)

Comment: This is done in OS X (Yosemite) via System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys (a button in the lower right)